# Open in memory word document via MS Word add-in created using VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I have been programming Add-In for Word. I loaded the document into memory as a `byte[]`. I need to open it in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Word can not open documents from memory streams. You have to use (temporary) file.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

public void MyWordFileReaderMethod()
{
   string filePath = @"c:\example.docx";
   var file = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
}
```

the object `file` would contain what you require.

EDIT 1

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"c:\tempfile.docx";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If you need to start the memory file with word there is no way but to put it into a temp file and use the code above. 2 processes cannot share data across process boundaries if i am not mistaken.

Comment: I have been programming add-ins for word. I loaded the document into memory. I need to open it in Word.

Comment: Your question is not specific and was a little confusing. the Process class is what you are looking for. will update the answer in a moment

Comment: Whether i know VSTO or not is irrelevant, you cannot use what's in your applications memory on another process. it blows away all security criteria of an operating system.

Comment: My Add-In runs in the same process as the Word. Knowledge of VSTO is still important.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question. i think you will attract more people with VSTO background. if its in the same process you shouldn't have a problem, but i'm afraid i cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file stored on HDD and want to open it in MS Word then why are you lading it into memory. You can directly open it using Process Class

```
Process wordDoc = new Process();
wordDoc.FileName = @"c:\example.docx";
wordDoc.Start();
```

Comment: I get a file as byte[] from a Web service, and do not want to save.